# Applying a transformation to all the text nodes inside a given node using lxml.html?

Tags: python, lxml

I would like to apply a *transformation*, say `uppercase`, to **all** the *text* nodes inside a given node. I came up with the following code which works fine for my sample input.

Is there something else that should be considered? I felt that the usage of `text` vs `tail` in `lxml` is a bit *asymmetric* because `text` needs to be applied to the main node and `tail` needs to be applied to the child node.

Can someone review this code?

```
import lxml.html   

def transform(node):
    if node.text:
        node.text = node.text.upper()
    for child in node.getchildren():
        if child.tail:
            child.tail = child.tail.upper()
        transform(child)
```

Here is the test case used:

```
html = """
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="great.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <title>Best Page Ever</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      Body Start
      <div id="1">
         Div 1 Start
         <div id="11">
            Div 11 Start
            Address 1
            <br>
            Address 2
            Div 11 End
         </div>
         <div id="12">
            Div 12 Start
            <div id="121">
              Inside Div 121
            </div>
            Div 12 End
         </div>
         Div 1 End
      </div>
      Body End
   </body>
</html>
"""

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

transform(root.get_element_by_id('121'))

print(lxml.html.tostring(root))
```